# Can’t connect to printer that is on my router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, printing, printer

I’m currently trying to setup my [Konica Minolta Magicolor 1690MF](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001Q3KMX0) on my network for my dad so our family can print from it. My dad is trying to print via Wi-Fi and was able to print after he wired his laptop to the router, however no one can print to the printer over Wi-Fi.

I’ve plugged the printer in, hooked it up via ethernet cable to my router; a [Netgear WNDR3800](http://support.netgear.com/product/wndr3800). I changed the settings on my printer to assign it a static IP of 192.168.1.110 and I set the subnet to match what my router config says, and restarted printer. After restart, I logged into my router and saw it in my attached devices like this.

[image]

It showed up, so my dad tried to ping that IP, and the ping timed out. I tried to add a device through the setup wizard on my computer, and the other computers in my house, but the device wasn't able to be found.

I’m at a loss now, and after a couple hours of searching, I still can’t seem to find anything.

Comment: @JakeGould I don't think it matters - if the PC and Printer are in the same subnet, the router doesn't participate other than at layer 2.

Comment: @DamianVu If your dad pings the router, and then does `arp -a` in the command line, do you see an entry corresponding to the ip and mac in your image?

Comment: @Paul yes when I do arp -a, I do see the ip and mac addresses of my printer there.

Comment: @JakeGould yes I'm trying to print via wi-fi. My dad was able to print after he wired his laptop to the router, however no one can print to the printer over wi-fi still

Comment: @DamianVu If you can see the arp entry, then the problem may not be networking.  Can you browse to it?

Comment: @Paul I'm not sure what you mean by browse to it. I can't see it while connected on wifi at all. 
One weird thing though: I can discover the printer and add it when I wire into my router, but when I'm connected via wifi to the same network I can't see the printer at all.